# Running flask command via crontab

Tags: python, flask, cron

I have a simple script that executes a flask command called sendemail (located in the "main" blueprint).

The "task" script, located in /home/ubuntu/tasks:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/app
source venv/bin/activate
flask main sendemail
deactivate
```

When I run (from anywhere, including the home directory)

```
bash /home/ubuntu/tasks/task
```

The function runs exactly as intended. However, when I add this same script to crontab, it produces an error, emailing me this message:

```
/home/ubuntu/tasks/task: line 4: flask: command not found
```

I've made sure that I have the latest flask installed and assume this might have something to do with the PATH variables - how can I fix/debug this?

Comment: Does `/home/ubuntu/app/venv/bin/activate` exist? Can you add `set -e` at the top of your scrip to trap any error…?

Comment: It does exist, and adding set -e produces the same error email

Answer (score 0):

The activation doesn’t work in the cron because you don’t have the same environment variables. You can use `set > /path/to/your.log` to diagnose…

You can simplify your scrip by calling Flask directly:

```
/home/ubuntu/app/venv/bin/flask main sendemail
```

Comment: Tried this - at first it wasn't working but then I re-installed my virtual environment and it works now. Thanks!